# How to skip Apache nutch from one step to next

Tags: apache, web-crawler, nutch

I am using apache Nutch 2.3. I want to skip fetch step of apache nutch to next step that is parsing i.e suppose that my crawling is in fetcing state and I want to go to parse step so that It completes early.

How I skip apache nutch from one step to next?

Answer (score 1):

Since Apache Nutch is based on Hadoop, different tasks has been applied step by step. It means Generate comes after finishing Inject. Fetch comes after Generate and etc. However for the Parsing step in order to change the default nutch behavior there is a configuration available.

```
<property>
    <name>fetcher.parse</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>For merge parse and fetch set it true</description>
</property>
```

The default value of fetcher.parse is false. You have to change it to true and put that inside `nutch-site.xml`. This parameter changes the default parsing mechanism for do the parse and fetch simultaneously. For other tasks of nutch I am afraid you have to do the development yourself.